# Can I set the instance of the ModelForm after I call is_valid?

Tags: django, django-forms

One of the custom fields of my `ModelForm` holds the pk for the database row to be edited. Therefore, I would like to first check if the form is valid, then set the instance using the cleaned pk field, then save the form. Is it even possible?

My workaround right now is to create a new `ModelForm` instance, which is not very neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form is overwriting all the information in the instance, you could simply set the primary key manually:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.pk = form.cleaned_data['pk_to_edit']
    obj.save()
    return ...
```

Comment: This is not a new instance, it is an existing one. So would this update the existing row with the given pk?

Comment: Yes, as I say, it will overwrite the entire row. Django uses the presence/absence of the `pk` field to determine whether to do an INSERT or UPDATE, so if you set it manually it will update that row.